# How to stop Shopify from triggering Google Analytics or Facebook Pixel before cookie consent is obtained from user

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, shopify, facebook-pixel

The EU Cookie Law requires you to obtain the user's consent before saving any cookies to their browser (which both Google Analytics and Facebook Pixel do). Shopify instructs you to use their integrations of Google Analytics/Pixel, because they're already fully integrated with their eCommerce. So somehow we have to stop Shopify from triggering analytics cookies before we get the user's consent.

I can't figure out how it is possible to do this.

As near as I can tell analytics is triggered by a variable called trekkie within {{ content_for_header }}, which is loaded in the head of theme.liquid

I can stop analytics all together if I just comment out {{ content_for_header }}, but that stops a heap of other important code from running as well, so it's not a viable solution.

Any thoughts on how to stop Shopify from running analytics, and then to trigger it later once I've gained the user's consent to use cookies?

Comment: You could consider using Google Tag Manager to control when these tags fire

Comment: Yeah, sadly if you do that you miss out on all their pre-built eCommerce config. That's why Shopify suggest you let them handle Google Analytics & Pixel, and that you should only use Google Tag Manager for other tags.

Comment: something like this can be achieved with Additional Google Analytics JavaScript logic available within settings but you'll need some specific code depending on your consent provider

Answer (score 1):

I found that enabling 'Use Enhanced Ecommerce.' resolved it for me.

Comment: Could you detail what the solution you mention would be?

Comment: Hi Paulo, Under where you enter the Google Analytics tracking code in Shopify (Themes > Preference) there is a checkbox with the label 'Use Enhanced Ecommerce.' Tick this option, then clear the cookies in your browser (in Google Chome you can do this using right-click > Inspect > Applications > Cookies, then right-click on your domain name and select Clear) and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks @Piers

(Themes > Preference) there is a checkbox with the label 'Use Enhanced Ecommerce.' Tick this option, then clear the cookies in your browser (in Google Chome you can do this using right-click > Inspect > Applications > Cookies, then right-click on your domain name and select Clear) and refresh. –